# Declare events of gridviewSecond which is inside gridviewFirst

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

have two gridviews. GridViewSecond is inside GridViewFirst. In code behind, how to declare events of GridViewSecond like PreRender, RowCommand, etc.?

My two gridviews:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFirst" runat="server"
    OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Des_Cargo" HeaderText="Cargo">
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="10">
                        <div id="div<%# Eval("Cod_Correl") %>" style="display: none; position: relative;" >
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSecond" runat="server"
                                OnRowDataBound="GridViewSecond_RowDataBound"
                                OnRowCommand="GridViewSecond_RowCommand"
                                OnPreRender="GridViewSecond_PreRender">
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cod_Cargo" DataField="Cod_Cargo" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                                        Visible="false">
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" BorderColor="#CFCFCF" BorderWidth="1px"></ItemStyle>
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="fondo-head-grid" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fecha de Carga" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFec_Carga" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fec_Carga","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewFec_Carga" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFec_Carga" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fec_Carga","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbkUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                                                Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel"
                                                Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </EditItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Insert"
                                                Text="Insertar"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                Text="Editar"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbkDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I can invoke GridViewSecond in this way:

```
Protected Sub GridViewFirst_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim oBL_Resolucion As New BL_Resolucion

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        If e.Row.DataItem Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim GridViewSecond As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvwResolDetalle"), GridView)

        Dim lblOrden As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblOrden"), Label)

        GridViewSecond.DataSource = oBL_Resolucion.Listar(_Cod_OP.ToString, lblOrden.Text)
        GridViewSecond.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

But can't declare GridViewSecond events like this:

```
Protected Sub GridViewSecond_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)                                   
    Dim count As Integer = GridViewSecond.Rows.Count                                           

    For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1                                                          
        Dim row As GridViewRow = GridViewSecond.Rows(i)                                        

        If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then                                       
            Dim lbtnEdit As LinkButton = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lnkEdit"), LinkButton)    

            If lbtnEdit IsNot Nothing Then                                                     
                lbtnEdit.Visible = False                                                       
            End If                                                                             

            Dim lbtnDelete As LinkButton = DirectCast(row.FindControl("lbkDelete"), LinkButton)
            If lbtnDelete IsNot Nothing Then                                                   
                lbtnDelete.Visible = False                                                     
            End If                                                                             
        End If                                                                                 
    Next                                                                                       
End Sub
```

It shows error like: "GridViewSecond is not declared."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Dim count As Integer = GridViewSecond.Rows.Count
```

You can use the `sender`, which is actually the `GridView`:

```
Dim gv As GridView
gv = DirectCast(sender, GridView)

Dim count As Integer = gv.Rows.Count
```